# I can't get the output for the below code

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner with c# and I can't get the output for the code below. Someone please help me with this. The result is not being displayed when I run the code. I'm sure that the error done here is a very silly one but I'm not able to identify it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float num, result;
            int opt;
            Console.Write("\t Enter your salary:");
            num = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\t Enter your option:");
            opt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (opt)
            {
                case 1:
                    result = num * (5 / 100);
                    Console.Write("\t You have to pay the tax of rupees: {0}", result);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = num * (8 / 100);
                    Console.Write("\t You have to pay the tax of rupees: {0}", result);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result = num * (5 / 100);
                    Console.Write("\t You have to pay the tax of rupees: {0}", result);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option...Please try again.");
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? You can't see anything on screen when you run it?

Comment: are you sure you are running this program ? do you have more than one projects in your solution?

Comment: Have you got your answer or still problem?

Comment: I entered the inputs and pressed enter but the result shown is 0. @shree.pat18

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that its running and I have only this project in my solution. @Selman22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code its all about brackets just change the sequence and you will get the output I have tried it in my VS 2012:-

```
        float num, result;
        int opt;
        Console.Write("\t Enter your salary:");
        num = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("\t Enter your option:");
        opt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (opt)
        {
            case 1:
                result = (num * 5) / 100;
                Console.Write("\t You have to pay the tax of rupees: {0}", result);
                break;
            case 2:
                result = (num * 8) / 100;
                Console.Write("\t You have to pay the tax of rupees: {0}", result);
                break;
            case 3:
                result = (num * 5) / 100;
                Console.Write("\t You have to pay the tax of rupees: {0}", result);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option...Please try again.");
                break;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

To understand more go through this :- http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s2p13.html

Comment: why downvotes? I have tried in my Visual studio and now its giving the result